# How to write this JavaScript if-else statement

Tags: php, javascript, if-statement

I'm currently using the backstretch.js script for full screen background images, I've got it working but I would like to add an if statement to check if an image is set, which are set via custom post types display that image, if not, the default image should be *link to image*

This is what I have so far, but it doesn't work and need help fixing it:

```
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery.backstretch.js"></script>
<script>
    var link = $.backstretch(
        "<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'upload_image', true); ?>")
    var altLink = '<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/not-set-default.jpg'
    if (x == link) {
        document.write(link)
    } else {
        document.write(altLink)
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What goes wrong with it?

Comment: altlink does not get displayed, I want to display the link in var altlink if var link is not set, or has no value, that's what I'm trying to do, it doesn't work right now.

Comment: Also x is nothing right now, not sure what I could compare it to to achieve what i want?

Comment: @user595600 If this script is in your `head`, then it would also output the link in the `head`. You should be using DOM manipulation functions to place it in the page where you want.

Comment: @user595600 I'm not sure what `$.backstretch` does, but you could just check `if (link)`, and it would probably execute as you want.